# How to read sqlite and decode run length encoded format in python?

Tags: python, sqlite, run-length-encoding

I am reading sqlite file having run length encoded format.

**code.py**

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("data.sqlite3")

#print(conn)     it prints object but decode function works on array instead of object also i don't have table name.
c = conn.cursor()
conn.close()
```

How can i decode the data inside it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just go through some tutotrials, you will get to know about this. Anyways, I'll give you entire code to play around with database and also to do what you want to do.
Here, enjoy

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


def create_connection(db_file):
""" create a database connection to the SQLite database
    specified by the db_file
:param db_file: database file
:return: Connection object or None
"""
try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
    return conn
except Error as e:
    print(e)

return None


def select_all_tasks(conn):
"""
Query all rows in the tasks table
:param conn: the Connection object
:return:
"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)


def select_task_by_priority(conn, priority):
"""
Query tasks by priority
:param conn: the Connection object
:param priority:
:return:
"""
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE priority=?", (priority,))

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)


def main():
database = "C:\\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db"

# create a database connection
conn = create_connection(database)
with conn:
    print("1. Query task by priority:")
    select_task_by_priority(conn,1)

    print("2. Query all tasks")
    select_all_tasks(conn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```